# why does my script wont append the ul in my class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this script to append new message from client but it wont append to my ul list, don't know why but when i check in console it print 2 object from class chat-message one there is the ul and one not, but from this script it only append to .chat-message class one time and in the html i only have the container class and in the new .chat-message i empty my .message-user class and only add the ul tag to used it later when append new data

here is the html script

```
    <div class="chat-message">
    </div>
```

here is my js script.

```
    function get_message_data(){
        $(".client-message").on("click",function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"msg",
                method:"get",
                data:{"data":this.id},
                success:function(response){
                    data_response = JSON.parse(response)
                    add_data = add_data +
                    '<div class="header-message" value='+data_response[0].line_name+'>'+
                        '<div class="image-profile">'+
                            '<img src='+data_response[0].line_image+' alt="image-message">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="username-profile">'+
                            '<label>'+data_response[0].line_name+'</label>'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<button id="btn-exit" onclick="exit_app()">X</button>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="message-user">'+
                        '<ul>'+
                        '</ul>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="footer-message-send">'+
                        '<div class="file-send">'+
                            '<label for="btn-file-input"><i class="fas fa-archive"></i></label>'+
                            '<button id="btn-file-input" style="display:none;"></button>'+
                            '<input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="send-message">'+
                            '<input type="text" name="yellow" class="textinput">'+
                        '</div>'+
                        '<div class="button-send">'+
                        '<label for="send-message-admini"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>'+
                            '<button id="send-message-admini" style="display:none;" type="button" value="submit"></button>'+
                        '</div>'+            
                    '</div>'
                    $(".chat-message").empty();
                    $(".chat-message").append(add_data);
                    for(var i = 0; i < data_response.length; i++){
                        var add_template =
                            '<li class="message-send-client">'+
                                '<div class="client-message-send">'+
                                    '<div class="message-header-send">'+
                                        '<img src='+data_response[i].line_image+'>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                    '<div class="user-message">'+
                                        '<label>'+data_response[i].line_name+'</label>'+
                                        '<p>'+data_response[i].message+'</p>'+
                                    '</div>'+
                                '</div>'+
                            '</li>'+
                        $('.message-user').find('ul').append(add_template)
                    }
                    send_admin_message();
                    var interval = setInterval(function(){
                        update_message();
                    },3000)
                }
            })
            id_user = this.id
        })
    }
```

Comment: just do it simple, run the loop for add_template  before , and  in  add_data  = message-user  div, do concat

Comment: but if i run the add_template first i cant get message-user class because it must append the chat message class first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here make it like this
see in ul i have added the templatedata

```
success:function(response){
    data_response = JSON.parse(response)
    var add_template = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < data_response.length; i++){
       // here this is creating list
        add_template += 
            '<li class="message-send-client">'+
                '<div class="client-message-send">'+
                    '<div class="message-header-send">'+
                        '<img src='+data_response[i].line_image+'>'+
                    '</div>'+
                    '<div class="user-message">'+
                        '<label>'+data_response[i].line_name+'</label>'+
                        '<p>'+data_response[i].message+'</p>'+
                    '</div>'+
                '</div>'+
            '</li>'+
    }
    
    add_data = add_data +
    '<div class="header-message" value='+data_response[0].line_name+'>'+
        '<div class="image-profile">'+
            '<img src='+data_response[0].line_image+' alt="image-message">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="username-profile">'+
            '<label>'+data_response[0].line_name+'</label>'+
        '</div>'+
        '<button id="btn-exit" onclick="exit_app()">X</button>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="message-user">'+
        '<ul>'+add_template+
        '</ul>'+
    '</div>'+
    '<div class="footer-message-send">'+
        '<div class="file-send">'+
            '<label for="btn-file-input"><i class="fas fa-archive"></i></label>'+
            '<button id="btn-file-input" style="display:none;"></button>'+
            '<input type="file" id="file-input" style="display: none;">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="send-message">'+
            '<input type="text" name="yellow" class="textinput">'+
        '</div>'+
        '<div class="button-send">'+
        '<label for="send-message-admini"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true"></i></label>'+
            '<button id="send-message-admini" style="display:none;" type="button" value="submit"></button>'+
        '</div>'+            
    '</div>'
    $(".chat-message").empty();
    $(".chat-message").append(add_data);
}
```

Comment: it work thanks..but i want to ask why does it show 2 unordered list still in my console when i only appending it once?

Comment: did not get it properly.  you can use .html instead of append as you are already emptying it.